# Confidence interval for proportions

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, confidence-interval, interpretation

I have some data like this:

```
id    pop   var
1     593   51
2     592   31
3     346   20
4    1214   70
5    1063   66
6    1370   71
```

each `id` represents a school. There are around 1847 of them, of which 1833 are unique . `pop` is the number of pupils in the school. `var` is the number of pupils with a particular trait. Interest in centered on the ratio of `var/pop` . I have used a binomial regression:

```
fit.bn <- glm(cbind(var,pop-var)~1, data=dt, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

which produced the results:

```
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.748516   0.003295  -834.2   <2e-16 ***
```

And to get the estimate for the proportion and it's confidence interval I used:

```
invlogit(coef(fit.bn))
invlogit(confint(fit.bn,level = 0.95))
```

where

```
invlogit <- function (x) { return(exp(x)/(1+exp(x))) }
```

which produced:

```
(Intercept) 
 0.06017054 

     2.5 %     97.5 % 
0.05980603 0.06053643
```

Is this a valid confidence interval for these data ? I was surprised that it was so narrow, but I guess this is because the total number observations is high (altogether, `sum(var)= 98008` and `sum(pop)=1628981`). Nevertheless, I am still unsure about this, due to:

```
sd(var/pop)
0.01373888
```

In other words the standard deviation of these proportions is around 20 times larger than their confidence interval.

Am I doing something stupid ? It just doesn't seem quite right.

I wondered about using a variance components model to try to account for variability between schools and within schools. I did this with

```
require(lme4)
fit.lme4 <- glmer(cbind(cbind(var,pop-var)~1+(1|id), data=dt, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

This produced:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id      (Intercept) 0.024125 0.15532 
Number of obs: 1847, groups: id, 1814

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.776882   0.005423  -327.7   <2e-16 ***
```

So I computed another confidence interval by:

```
invlogit(-1.776882  + (c(-1.96,1.96)* 0.005423))
0.1433781 0.1460089
```

which is wider than the first one, but the estimate is very different. Is this a valid procedure ? How do I interpret this estimate and confidence interval as compared to the first one ? And how do I interpret the variance of the random effects ?  Am I barking up the wrong tree ?

**Update:**

Here is a histogram of `var/pop`
[image]

Comment: I assume you have multiple 'var's and 'pop's per school? If so the glmer model is correct. CI - remember that the confidence interval is inversely proportional to the n, so if you have lots of schools your confidence interval will get smaller. Also, it doesn't seem like you have very much variability in the proportions for the snippet of data you gave. So the CIs seem ok to me.

Comment: @MattAlbrecht, no, the data is aggregated so there is just 1 `var` and `pop` per school..........

Comment: I get error messages with glmer when there is only one measure per id: {glmerx <- glmer(cbind(var, pop-var) ~  1 + (1|id), data=df1, family=binomial)} "Number of levels of a grouping factor for the random effects is *equal* to n, the number of observations". You have some double up id numbers in there as indicated by the glmer output "Number of obs: 1847, groups: id, 1814" 1847-1814 = 33 double ups

Comment: @MattAlbrecht sorry you are right. I was told the data are all for unique schools, so I don't know whey there are duplicate IDs.

Comment: @MattAlbrecht I have updated the question to reflect the duplicate ids.

Comment: You really should find why you have dup IDs. Error? Something else?